# Artifactory plugin for VSTS not publishing build

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, azure-pipelines

I've installed the JFrog artifactory plugin in my vsts instance and am trying out a test build to see what gets published. I've setup the plugin as per these docs https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VS+Team+Services+Artifactory+Plugin and when I run a build I can see an OPTIONS request in the artifactory log, so VSTS is communicating with my server, but no builds get stored in artifactory.

Have I missed something?

This is my artifactory config for the build
[image]

Excerpt from Artifactory request log
`20170824152059|0|REQUEST|*****|non_authenticated_user|OPTIONS|/api/build/myTestProject-CI/47|HTTP/1.1|401|0`

It looks like the authentication details I've put in aren't being used, hence the 401. Also, I only see that OPTIONS request in the artifactory log if I run the VSTS build with `system.debug=true`.

I've tried enabling anonymous access in artifactory, but the only difference that makes is the OPTIONS request returns 400. I still don't see any builds or any artifacts.

`20170824152704|638|REQUEST|*****|anonymous|OPTIONS|/api/build/myTestProject-CI/48|HTTP/1.1|200|0`

And I don't see any mention of artifactory in the vsts build log, even with `system.debug=true`

This is my job config, very simple dummy build at the moment

[image]

Comment: What're task with settings of build definitioin? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Screenshot of build job added to post. Job output here: https://pastebin.com/RnzCVidG. This generated this artifactory request: `20170831122248|547|REQUEST|11.22.33.44|anonymous|OPTIONS|/api/build/myTestProject-CI/51|HTTP/1.1|200|0`

Comment: Where do you get Artifactory request log? You need to add JFrog Artifactory Deployer task to publish artifacts to Artifactory server, so add it to your build definition and try again.

Comment: I've added the deployer task and the aritact uploads but build info upload fails due to self-signed cert. The version of the jfrog cli downloaded (1.4.1) is so old that I don't think it supports the most recent fixes in this area.

Comment: You can specify jfrog cli in the task directly.

Comment: Thanks, missed that. So it's now using v1.10.3 of the cli and still fails with `System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` when uploading build info to a an artifactory with a self signed cert.

Comment: Raised with jfrog https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/93

Comment: What's the detail log? Do you use private build agent? What's the result if you [upload files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles) through command line manually?